# RIA services loading related entities

Tags: entity-framework, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I have 2 entities with a navigational property. But i'm having a problem when loading them from silverlight.

lets say:

Entity 1: Id, entity_2_id;
entity 2: Id

so i load Entities 1:

```
_context.load(_context.getAllEntities1(), data =>
    {
         entities1 = data.Entities;
    }
```

at this time `entities1.First().entity2;` is a null.

after that i load Entites 2:

```
_context.load(_context.getAllEntities2(), data =>
    {
         entities2 = data.Entities;
    }
```

and `entities1.First().entity2;` is still a null.

Shouldn't the context be filling those out?

Thanks.

Update to the question:

Yes we can use includes to load related data to the entities we are loading.

But what i'm asking is when loading them separately shouldn't the context detect that we have entities loaded that are related to other loaded entitys and fill their relations?

Answer (score 1):

In the Ria server-side syntax you have to do two things to send to the client the related entities:

1. In the Metadata for Entity1 decorate the property Entity2 (or whatever your navigational property is) with `[Include]`.
2. When querying (with Linq I guess), reference the relation: return `this.ObjectContext.Entities1.Include("YourNavigationalPropertyHere");`

Comment: Yes i do that if i want to load the entities related to that query. I'll updated the question.